# Which page event could be used for the following purpose?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have a page which is having the following

Some ddl's for Filter the data

- A Submit button
- A export Button
- A GridView

In general We show/hide Export button if submit query results more than zero rows/ no rows

### **NOTE:**

It is not only the case for one button but there would be more and i will have to check for the permission for every where i show /hide the buttons

#### For Example

```
Page_Load

showHideAsPerPermission(btnExport);


BtnSubmitClick()

if rows>0
    btnExport.Visible = true;
else
    btnExport.Visible = false;
```

But for the purpose of Permission

I want to set **Export button visibility to true/false** after **BtnSubmit_click** (or all controls events like selected index change, textChanged etc.) event has fired

**A little Explanation of my problem**

Say if you have permission to export then it only visible when rows>0 and if you don't have then it invisible even rows>0 but if i set the permission on page load and then i set exports visibility true for rows > 0 then it is visible even you don't have permission so is there any event which fires after control events

Is there any method which i can utilize for this purpose

I have read the following events and tried Page_Unload event which actually does nothing cause page is already rendered

So is there any method which could accomplish my task

[image]

### Note:

As per my Knowledge there is no such Event so can i create a custom page event?

Comment: After page_load button_click will called and i will there show/ hide export button

Comment: That's fine. You can set all visibilities in page_load and also in the click event.

Comment: I don't want to set in both

Comment: You can set it in either place.

Comment: there would be a lot of buttons like edit, export, print etc.

Comment: So that's three lines of code. You don't even need an `if` statement. Just say `btnExport.Visible = rows>0`.

Comment: I am not even bothering lines of code but I am bothering of no of places where i would like to tackle with this

and the major concern is the permission if user is permitted then and only then it should visible regardless the row count

Comment: Well, you apparently have to set the visibility on the initial Page_Load based on the number of rows. Then on postback (`BtnSubmit_click`) you need to change it again. I don't understand your question. I said where to tackle -- just do it in Page_Load (if it isn't a post-back). If you need to do something specific in `BtnSubmit_click` then yes you will have to have some code there too.

Comment: Get rid of that big graphic and include some code if you are having a problem with your code.

Comment: Its simple if you have permission to export then it only visible when rows>0 and if you don't have then it invisible even rows>0 but if i set the permission on page load and then i set exports visibility true for rows > 0 then it is visible even you don't have permission

so is there any event which fires after controlevents

Comment: @MikeSmithDev As per my Knowledge there is no Such Event

Comment: You haven't explained why you need to re-set the visibility on `BtnSubmit_click`. Please clarify your question. It sounds like "I am setting the button visibility correctly and then later I'm setting it incorrectly." You set the visibility on Page_Load if it isn't a post back. If you need to change the visibility later based on an event (click, index change, etc), then you properly set it inside there. I recommend you just attempt it and if you have any issues, post them here.

Comment: See I set first on Page_load as per permission and then as per row count but at this stage i should reset the permission after setting as per row count which actually i want to do in that event i was looking for so that i will use only that event not page_load so permission will automatically will be set

Comment: Remove the graphic. Include your code. State the problem with visibilities. We can't help fix your code if there is no code.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in `Page_Load`.

Keep in mind, on `BtnSubmit_click`, the page will post back, `Page_Load` is going to execute again (so you'll probably need something like `if (!IsPostback)`...), and then `BtnSubmit_click`.